# Append item to last object in Svelte Store

Tags: svelte

I am trying to create a Svelte app that stores chess moves in an array. Every time a new white move is created, a new object in the array should be created. Creating a black move should simply update the field *black_move* in the last object. However, the output doesn't react to this update until the white move button is pressed again. What could be the issue? The REPL is [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/47d34cc841724a03b689f6fbf63a183a?version=3.44.1).

```js
import { writableArray } from './store.js';
    
    const moveWhite = () => {
        $writableArray = [...$writableArray, {
            white_move: 'a1-a2',
            black_move: ''
        }];
    };
    const moveBlack = () => {
        $writableArray.at(-1).black_move = 'b1-b2' 
    };
  
<button on:click={moveWhite}>
    Move White
</button>
<button on:click={moveBlack}>
    Move Black
</button>

{#each $writableArray as item}
    {item.white_move} {item.black_move}
{/each}
```

The store is defined as follows:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const writableArray = writable([]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the assignment

```js
const moveBlack = () => {
        $writableArray.at(-1).black_move = 'b1-b2' 
        $writableArray = $writableArray
    };
```

is a good solution for inside a component, since it's a bit more concise than using `.update()`. Like already mentioned the spread operator is not necessary, what's important is the assignment. Have a look at the docs ['assignments are "reactive"'](https://svelte.dev/docs#2_Assignments_are_reactive)

And to show yet another approach, instead of declaring the functions inside `App.svelte` you could also make a custom store an put them there -> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4574efd460d741f7847476a945ca4f16?version=3.44.1)

###### store.js

```js
import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

export const movesArray = (() => {
    const {subscribe, set, update} = writable([])
    return {
        subscribe,
//      set, // optional if needed outside store
//      update, // optional if needed outside store
        moveWhite() {
            update(store => {
                return [...store, { white_move: 'a1-a2', black_move: ''}]
            })
        },
        moveBlack(move) {
            update(store => {
                store.at(-1).black_move = move
                return store // this line is important
            })
        }       
    }   
})();
```

###### App.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { movesArray } from './store.js';        
</script>

<button on:click={movesArray.moveWhite}>
    Move White
</button>
<button on:click={() => movesArray.moveBlack('b1-b2')}>
    Move Black
</button>

{#each $movesArray as item}
<p>
    {item.white_move} {item.black_move}
</p>
{/each}
```

Comment: I have to say, I like this answer the best. All answers work but this makes the store interface to other modules cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `update` method, like:

```
writableArray.update(existingValue => ([...existingValue, newMove]));
```

So as for your example it can look like:

```
<script>
    import { writableArray } from './store.js';
    
    const moveWhite = () => {   
        writableArray.update(s => ([...s, {
            white_move: 'a1-a2',
            black_move: ''
        }]));
    };
    
    const moveBlack = () => {       
        writableArray.update(s => {
            s.at(-1).black_move = 'b1-b2'           
            
            return s
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following also works, but since I'm new to Svelte, I'm not sure it's the recommended approach:

```js
const moveBlack = () => {
        $writableArray.at(-1).black_move = 'b1-b2' 
        $writableArray = [...$writableArray]
    };
```

Comment: So would `$writableArray = $writableArray` no need for the spread operator, just need to update the value.